# How to display new entries of mysql database in jpanel instead without relaunching the application?

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jdbc

I am looking a java solution that can display all new entries of mysql jdbc database instead without restarting the application just like ajax for web-application but I want the same feature as ajax for java desktop application. Anybody know about this????

I am fetching data from this:

```
conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

stmt = conn.createStatement();
String select = "SELECT Complete from classes";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);

List<JButton> listCustomiseJCB = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    String complete = rs.getString("Complete");
    String heading = complete;
    listCustomiseJCB.add(new JButton(heading));
}
```

Comment: 1. Create a query that gets the new entries. 2. Run the query, in a background thread as always. 3. Display the results from the query in your JPanel view. 4. If still stuck, ask a much better and more specific question, one that shows your code, and shows exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34442454/edit). Please also improve your question by making it more specific since your current code is not enough to allow us to know what you may be doing wrong. Please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to see what we need.

Comment: Ok I add code in my question

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 2):

My main suggestion at this stage and based on what you've posted is for you to create an object to hold the  results of your query, a `List<String>` might be all you need if you're only extracting a single column of data, and then create a view, a JPanel, that remains in your GUI, but that has been written to change what it displays based on the results of your query. Perhaps the view class can have a method that accepts a `List<String>` parameter and then uses that information to change what it displays. For instance, if that data should be held in a column of JButtons (a strange choice, but I can see some uses for it), then in your method, you could have the view JPanel remove all current buttons from an inner JPanel, and then add new JButtons that contain the Strings from the database.

If you need more detailed help, you'll likely need to post a more detailed question.

Also, as alluded to in MadProgrammer's comment, often the best way to display database results in a Swing GUI is via JLists for simple data display and JTable for more complex (i.e., multi-column, editable cell) display and interaction. Either of these would display selectable rows of data.